# How to know if the browser has specific presentation for a HTML5 form's element?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cross-browser, fallback

I'd like to use HTML5's new inputs elements like `type="number"`, `type="color"`, etc.

Google Chrome, handles these with custom user interfaces which do the job just fine.

In opposition, Firefox keeps things way more basic leaving those with the usual `type="text"` interface look and feel.

I'd like to detect when the browser doesn't provide extra enhancement like Google does so I can provide my own.

How can that be done?

Comment: Check "interface enhancement" there: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/8-range.html with the already well supported "range" type.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect whether the browser supports the new types by creating one and seeing what its type is; the type will be the HTML5 type (`number`, `color`, etc.) if it's supported, or `text` if not:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'number');
if (input.type === 'number') {
    // Supported
}
else {
    // Not supported
}
```

Comment: The browser could support the feature without providing interface enhancement, right? My question is about detecting the enhancement (even if presumably, supporting the input type would lead to providing interface enhancement).

Comment: (Side note: doesn't Modernizr provide the same functionality your code does?)

Comment: If a browser doesn't support that input type, it will fallback to a text-based input. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpfC5/) in Firefox and Chrome to see the difference.

Comment: I know that. But supporting a type doesn't mean providing a useful interface enhancement. It could for instance just be about checking if the color is valid or even less. The W3 specs don't say anything about how those should be handled, it just says they exist.

Comment: What do you mean with "interface enhancement"?

Comment: Check, how type="range" gets rendered : http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/8-range.html that's what I refer as "interface enhancement".

Comment: @Serge: Yes, I'm expect Modernizr uses a check like that, as it's how you check for this sort of thing. I'm not seeing why you're raising that...? If the browser supports the type of input, the UI of that is up to the browser; barring taking a screenshot, I don't believe you can detect the UI, just the support.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't believe you can detect the UI either, but I'm not sure you can't either. Maybe one knows. // If I asked about Modernizr (which I'm not familiar with yet) is because I feel it's better not to reinvent the wheel while a library is becoming an industry standard.

Comment: @Serge: Sure, I could have said "Here's how you do it...or you could use Modernizr" (except I don't *know* that Modernizr detects it; I just suspect it does).

Comment: I don't blame you about not mentioning Modernizr. I just though it was worth mentioning for other people interested by the question and who might not know (or think) about modernizr.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Firefox doesn't support [numeric inputs](http://caniuse.com/input-number) or [color inputs](http://caniuse.com/input-color), but it will in the next major release. To detect if it is supported use:

```
function supportsInput(type) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', type);
  if (input.type === type) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(supportsInput('color') ? 'true' : 'false');
console.log(supportsInput('number') ? 'true' : 'false');
```

Comment: Your answer is similar to T.J.'s one. So I'll just comment that one.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: MY FF29beta on Mac shows the right UI for number and color!

Short answer is: you can't detect what the user sees. You can only check the API and assume that browser with the API also have implemented the UI. If a browser is standards compiliant, this assumption should be true.

So the most simple test is to check wether the content attribute is also reflected by the idl attribute:

```
function supportsInput(type) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', type);
  return (input.type === type);
}
```

The Modernizr test does a little bit more to give you a more accurate result, mainly to exclude old webkit browsers. You can split the new input types in three categories: 1. simple sematnic type (i.e. "search"), 2. there are types with some special validation constraints (i.e. type="email") and 3. there are types with special UI (and validation constraint), but also with an enhanced value sanitization algorithm.

This means you can enhance your detects by doing the following:

```
var constrainTypes = {email: 1, url: 1};
var widgetTypes = {date: 1, month: 1, range: 1, color: 1, week: 1, number: 1};
function supportsInput(type) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    var ret = false;
    var val = '!#';
    input.setAttribute('type', type);
    if (input.type === type) {
        input.value = val;
        if (constrainTypes[type]) {
            ret = input.checkValidity && !input.checkValidity();
        } else if (widgetTypes[type]) {
            ret = input.value != val;
        } else {
            ret = true;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, is this extended check the same as what Modernizr uses? Perhaps you could add a link to the relevant source and/or documentation?